# How to select a date "span" from this table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `SELECT` result that contain columns with date. This is some data from the result:

```
ID   Name    status         start_date      end_date
A1   John    Planning       2017-03-03      2017-03-05
A1   John    Realizing      2017-03-05      2017-04-05
A1   John    Finishing      2017-04-05      2017-04-15
A1   John    Launching      2017-04-15      2017-04-16
A2   Lisa    Planning       2017-03-09      2017-03-13
A2   Lisa    Realizing      2017-03-13         NULL
```

I'd like to know the progress status from `planning -> Realizing -> Finishing -> Launching` for each `ID`.

I've used this query but I don't know if it will be reliable and fast enough. The real table contain thousand of values.

`SELECT x.id, x.name, CONCAT_WS(' to ', MIN(x.start_date), MAX(x.end_date)) AS progress FROM (SELECT * FROM team_project WHERE ID = 'A1')x`

Expected output :

```
Name             Progress               total
John     2017-03-03 to 2017-04-16      44 days
Lisa     2017-03-09 to NOW               -
```

Comment: Are you using a php page?

Comment: @Brijesh Yes I use PHP. But, I'd like to have the expected result in mysql if possible.

Comment: Can i see your php code?

Comment: The PHP code is for echoing the result only. I haven't create it yet. I'm stuck in this MySQL issue.

Comment: So the above code is for your sql code and not for php coe?

Comment: What if Mark did the finishing? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry each person has same cycle of work. Please re-read my question

Comment: If the accepted answer is satisfactory then fine. Otherwise, please rewrite the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think with`group by` you can  like this

```
SELECT id, name, CONCAT_WS(' to ', MIN(start_date), MAX(end_date)) AS progress 
FROM team_project group by ID
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. How to add `NOW` as a text  if the end_date has `NULL` value ?

Comment: `ifnull( MAX(end_date),CURDATE())`

Comment: This makes grave assumptions about the data set which might not be true.

Comment: @Strawberry what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query without **GROUP BY**

```
SELECT
    tp1.`name`,
    CONCAT(tp1.start_date, ' to ',
        IF(tp2.end_date IS NULL, 'NOW', tp2.end_date)) AS Progress,
    DATEDIFF(IF(tp2.end_date IS NULL, NOW(), tp2.end_date),tp1.start_date) AS total
FROM team_project tp1
LEFT JOIN team_project tp2 ON tp1.id = tp2.id AND tp2.status 'Realizing'
WHERE tp1.status ='Planning';
```